# How use svg or qml shapes for template on my application

Tags: qt, svg, qml, qtquick2, shapes

I want to create an application for dispaly poem and I want to use Eslimi arts for frame or template to display these peoms .an example of Eslimi are in [this page](https://torobche.com/vip/islamic-tiling-189) and [here](https://torobche.com/vip/islamic-tiling-181) .But I have a problem with multiple screen size on mobile and desktops,For example I deployed my app on some are good but on and some are small because I use jpg file of these arts,So the jpg file could not adjust himself for be taller or wider.So I decided to pars these svg files to multiple parts and make them display progammatically aroud the poems.Untile

In [Shapes Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-shapes-example.html) there is a Tiger.qml file like below

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.12

Shape {
    asynchronous: true
    width: 494; height: 510

    ShapePath {
        fillColor: "#ffffff"
        strokeColor: "#000000"
        strokeWidth: 0.172
        PathMove { x: -122.304; y: 84.285 }
        PathCubic { control1X: -122.304; control1Y: 84.285; control2X: -122.203; control2Y: 86.179; x: -123.027; y: 86.16 }
        PathCubic { control1X: -123.851; control1Y: 86.141; control2X: -140.305; control2Y: 38.066; x: -160.833; y: 40.309 }
        PathCubic { control1X: -160.833; control1Y: 40.309; control2X: -143.05; control2Y: 32.956; x: -122.304; y: 84.285 }
    }
}
```

Now I have a svg file like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#282F68;}
    .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st2{fill:#91D0D5;}
</style>
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M474.1,130.5c-56.1,11.6-103.7-45.8-157,21.2C348.5,72.1,274.8,59.4,256.7,5c-0.2,0.6-0.5,1.2-0.7,1.8
            c-0.2-0.6-0.5-1.1-0.7-1.8c-18.1,54.4-91.7,67-60.3,146.7c-53.4-67-101-9.7-157-21.2c38,42.8,12,113.1,96.7,125.7
            C50,268.9,76,338.7,37.9,381.5c56.1-11.5,103.7,46.2,157-20.8c-31.4,79.7,42.2,92,60.3,146.3c0.2-0.6,0.5-1.2,0.7-1.8
            c0.2,0.6,0.5,1.1,0.7,1.8c18.1-54.4,91.7-66.6,60.3-146.3c53.3,67,101,9.3,157,20.8c-38-42.8-12-112.6-96.7-125.2
            C462,243.6,436,173.3,474.1,130.5z"/>
        <g>
            <path class="st1" d="M255.3,162.2c0.3-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.7-0.4c0.3,0.1,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.4c42.5-19,34.2-57.3,0-92.6
                c-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.6-0.7,0.9c-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.7-0.9C221.1,104.9,212.8,143.2,255.3,162.2z"/>
            <path class="st1" d="M93.6,162.9c13.5,47.2,42.5,73.5,80.2,46.3C178.6,162.9,141.2,150.9,93.6,162.9z"/>
            <path class="st1" d="M93.6,349.5c47.6,12,85,0,80.2-46.3C136.1,276,107.1,302.3,93.6,349.5z"/>
            <path class="st1" d="M338.2,303.3c-4.8,46.2,32.6,58.2,80.2,46.3C404.9,302.3,375.9,276,338.2,303.3z"/>
            <path class="st1" d="M256.8,350.2c-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.5c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.5c-42.5,19-34.2,57.4,0,92.6
                c0.3-0.3,0.5-0.6,0.8-0.9c0.3,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.9C291,407.6,299.3,369.2,256.8,350.2z"/>
            <path class="st1" d="M338.2,209.1c37.7,27.3,66.7,1,80.2-46.3C370.8,150.9,333.4,162.9,338.2,209.1z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <path class="st2" d="M310.3,284.4c17,28.4-33.1,57.4-49.2,28.4c-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.5-0.7,0.8c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.4-0.7-0.8
                c-16.1,29-66.2-0.1-49.2-28.4c-33.1,0.5-33.1-57.3,0-56.8c-16.9-28.4,33.1-57.3,49.2-28.3c0.2-0.3,0.5-0.5,0.7-0.8
                c0.2,0.3,0.5,0.5,0.7,0.8c16.2-29,66.2-0.1,49.2,28.3C343.4,227,343.4,284.9,310.3,284.4z"/>
        </g>
        <path class="st1" d="M287.4,256c0-18-13.5-27.1-27-27.1c-13.5,0.1-27,9.1-27,27.1c0,18,13.5,27.1,27,27.1
            C273.9,283.1,287.4,274,287.4,256z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

This svg file is a simplified of complex svg file .So I don't know how do the works.Shold I convert svg to qml shapes? shoudl I convert svg to qquickitem? or what? Does any one know How Should I work this?

Comment: why don't you just use one big Image (with source: your.svg) as a background and a text on it? I mean what an advantage to use several parts of the same image? Using only one significantly simplify the code.

Comment: @ I have created one app like this in [here](https://cafebazaar.ir/app/org.jooya.shakhehnabat) but it don' display good when screen is taller so,the picuter should be created on realtime or programmaticlally

Comment: @mohsen you can use `sourceSize` property of `Image` and then reload the image when necessary.